# ORA-29283: invalid file operation ORA-06512: at “SYS.UTL_FILE”, line 475

Tags: oracle, unix, oracle10g

i have a problem in writing in my Solaris 10 OS via my Oracle 10g.
i checked the permission and everything but the problem that the same code sometime it works and sometime it gives me that error.

i already create a directory and grant read and write privilege and check the OS permission.

Comment: Yes i am using RAC .... and each instance has it own file system.. if it a problem what is the solution.

Comment: Thank you.... i solved it ..... i was trying to execute the procedure from the instance on the other node

Answer (score 0):

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ oerr ora 29283
29283, 00000, "invalid file operation"
// *Cause:  An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does
//          not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the 
//          operating system.
// *Action: Verify file and directory access privileges on the file system,
//          and if reading, verify that the file exists.
```

> i checked the permission and everything but the problem that the same code sometime it works and sometime it gives me that error.

Well, you have ensured that there is no issues regarding privileges then you need to very that the file involved in the operation is exist or not.Sometimes it may not find the required file.

**Update**

As you said you are using Oracle RAC , probably the file is being stored in only one node and whenever you get connected to another node, due toload balancing or instance failure, the directory storing the files is no longer accessible.

Now, you should use cluster file system or NFS to store these file and mount point  must be same and accessible across all nodes.

Comment: i already check everything .... what i am wondering that sometime it works and sometimes it does not work without changing anything. and yes the file exist ...